# How to open dialog above all screens in flutter, when using go_router?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

```
    final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<InactivityCubit>(
      create: (_) => inject<InactivityCubit>(),
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        builder: (context, widget) {
          return Container(
            child: BlocListener<InactivityCubit, InactivityState>(
              listener: (context, state) => state.whenOrNull(
                showDialog: () {
                  final currentContext = navigatorKey.currentContext!;
                  AmazingDialog.show(currentContext!);
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              child: widget,
            ),
          );
        },
        theme: appTheme,
        routerConfig: inject<GoRouter>(),
        localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
        supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to open dialog above all screens in flutter, when using go_router? In my code I have an error because navigatorKey.currentContext is null.

Answer (score 0):

To open a dialog above all screens in Flutter using the provided code snippet, you can use the `showDialog` function along with the `navigatorKey` to ensure the dialog is displayed on top of all screens. :

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<InactivityCubit>(
      create: (_) => InactivityCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        onGenerateRoute: GoRouter
            .onGenerateRoute, // Update with your actual onGenerateRoute implementation

        builder: (context, widget) {
          return Container(
            child: BlocListener<InactivityCubit, InactivityState>(
              listener: (context, state) => state.whenOrNull(
                showDialog: () {
                  final currentContext = navigatorKey.currentContext!;
                  showDialog(
                    context: currentContext,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AmazingDialog(); // Replace with your dialog widget
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              child: widget,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GoRouter {
  static Route<dynamic>? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Implement your custom route generation logic here
    // Return the appropriate MaterialPageRoute or other custom route based on the settings
    return null;
  }
}
```

In this  code, the `navigatorKey` is set on the `MaterialApp.router` widget using the `navigatorKey` property. Then, within the `BlocListener`, when the `showDialog` state is triggered, `showDialog` is called with the `currentContext` obtained from `navigatorKey.currentContext`.

With these changes, the dialog will be displayed on top of all screens.

Comment: In my case I don't have navigatorKey property in MaterialApp.router.

Comment: you can create a global  variable with navigator key as on the 1st line